# SQLite epoch time in milliseconds

Tags: sqlite, time

I have a time column in a table which is supposed to represent the time (on the server), in milliseconds since the Epoch, when the record was created.

However, `strftime("%s")` returns an integer, omitting the millisecond value.

It appears the `strftime("%f")` returns a second value relative to the current minute, and a millisecond value that is synchronized with both the second of the minute and the epoch.

So it appears that I can get the value I want using this rather convoluted statement:

```
select CAST(strftime('%s','now') || '.' || substr(strftime('%f','now'),4,3) AS REAL)
```

Is this reliable?  My main concern is the fact that I have to call `strftime()` twice, is it possible that the second value will advance between calls so that I get (for example) `4.999` when I should get `3.999`?  I can imagine maybe creating a temporary table to store the results of `strftime("%f %s")` and then taking the `substr` of two separate selects, but this is even more convoluted and I'm not sure if it is necessary (is SQLite smart enough to only call `strftime()` once and return the same result twice?) Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is safe.  From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html),

```
The 'now' argument to date and time functions always returns
exactly the same value for multiple invocations within the same 
sqlite3_step() call.
```

This can be verified with the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE   cnt(x,y) AS (
    SELECT 1,1
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        x+1,
        CAST(strftime('%s','now') || '.' || substr(strftime('%f','now'),4,3) AS REAL) 
    FROM cnt
    LIMIT 10000)
SELECT x,y FROM cnt;
```

On my machine this query takes 40ms, but all time values are the same.